# Graphgist - local database

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I'm interested in Graphgist and was reading through some pages.
I didn't find if there is a possibility to connect my local Neo4j database with a graphgist?

Can someone tell me more?

Thanks a lot and Greetings

Tobias

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at the OpenSource repository of GraphGist CMS, clone it and configure it to use your local neo4j connection.

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/graphgist-cms